# Java: Как восстановить объект из JSON-строки на сервере?

Tags: java, json

Есть класс User:

```
 public class User{


 private String login;
 private String password;

 public User(){
     this(null, null);
 }

 public User(String login, String password){
     this.login = login;
     this.password = password;
 }

 public String getLogin() {
     return login;
 }

 public void setLogin(String login) {
     this.login = login;
 }

 public String getPassword() {
     return password;
 }

 public void setPassword(String password) {
     this.password=password;
 }
}
```

Я его преобразую в JSON строку с помощью вот этого кода:

```
public String toJson(Object obj){
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    try{
        return gson.toJson(obj);
    }catch(JsonSyntaxException jse){
        return null;
    }
}
```

И отправляю строку с клиента на сервер(Вся работа клиента и сервера реализована на сокетах) , а на сервере создаю объект с помощью вот этого кода , из строки , которая пришла от клиента:

```
public <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> classOfT){
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    try{
        return gson.fromJson(json, classOfT);
    }catch(JsonSyntaxException jse){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Но на сервере выдается ошибка :

> Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at chat.server.ChatServer.onReceiveString(ChatServer.java:49)//В этой строке я пытаюсь вызвать getLogin() из класса созданного из строки JSON
>       at chat.network.TCPConnection$1.run(TCPConnection.java:35)//Тут код , который читает строку, которая  прилетела от клиента
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Не разберусь в чем проблема . Тестил чисто на клиенте преобразовывать объект в JSON строку и создавать объект из этой же JSON строки , и все работает, а если отправляю эту строку на сервер , то на сервере объект создать не получается.

Дополнение:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 2 path $.
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:897)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773)
at chat.server.ChatServer.fromJson(ChatServer.java:83)
at chat.server.ChatServer.onReceiveString(ChatServer.java:48)
at chat.network.TCPConnection$1.run(TCPConnection.java:35)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 2 path $.
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1401)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:494)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.hasNext(JsonReader.java:414)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:214)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
... 7 more
```

Comment: Если перед `return null;` добавить `jse.printStackTrace();` будет проще разобраться в чём проблема.

Comment: Добавил , смотрите результат

Comment: Подозреваю, что вы пытаетесь преобразовать json-файл в объект раньше, чем приняли его полностью.

Comment: Все , разобрался , спасибо , что подсказали .

Comment: Выходило , что у меня каждая строка JSON отправлялась отдельно на сервер , чуток подправил у себя код , JSON отправляется сразу одной строкой